PDF's image extracted using Pymupdf doesn't appear on browser
I'm trying to convert pdf to html using Pymupdf. I was able to get both texts and images with Page.get_text("dict"). Currently I successfully put the images inside an img tag, however, for some cases, the images don't have the same color as the original images from the pdf ( maybe because they are inline images since they don't appear using Page.get_images() ). In the code I changed the background to black to see if the images are rendering
Here is my code to convert pdf to HTML:
def text2html(page: fitz.Page) -> str:
    text = page.get_text("dict")
    html = f'<div class="page" style="position:relative;width:{text["width"]}px;height:{text["height"]}px;background:black">'

    for block in text["blocks"]:
        # Image block
        if block["type"] == 1:
            img_base64 = base64.b64encode(block["image"]).decode("utf-8")
            html += f"""
            <img style="position: absolute; top: {block["bbox"][0]}px; left: {block["bbox"][1]}px;
                width: {block["bbox"][2] - block["bbox"][0]}px; height: {block["bbox"][3] - block["bbox"][1]}px;"
                src="data:image/{block["ext"]};base64,{img_base64}" alt="img">
            """
    
        elif block["type"] == 0:
            pass
    
    # Closing the main div
    return html + "</div>"

Here is the pdf file I used: pdf
Here is how the result HTML looked like: 
Side note: ( It seems that the position and length of the lines are wrong as well)
